# Sum letters are not two different

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

The following letters all have something in common which may not be obvious at a first glance:

```
A B D H P
```

No other letters share this attribute.

**Hint**

> There are no misspellings or typos in the title of this question. Maybe a clue though.

More hints may follow if the question is not answered.

Some great answers so far all of which I have upvoted but none of which are exactly what I am looking for.

**Hint 2**

> The number `0` and the character `(` also have the same property. I only said no other letters share it ;-)

**Hint 3**

> As correctly identified by @RedBaron the ASCII table is key here. There is a good reason why "sum" is mentioned in the title and there are two reasons why "two" is mentioned.

Comment: Are you sure B shouldn't be included too?

Comment: @Deusovi You are indeed correct. I had missed that. I'll update the question. Thanks.

Comment: Does a `!` also share this property?

Comment: @Akari Yes it does. I have not listed them all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The property seems to be related to:

> Binary equivalents of the symbols/alphabets etc.

**Explanation:**

> Binary equivalents for the following can be written as:
>  
>  `A -- 01000001`
>  
>  `B -- 01000010`
>  
>  `D -- 01000100`
>  
>  `H -- 01001000`
>  
>  `P -- 01010000`
>  
>  `0 -- 00110000`
>  
>  `( -- 00101000`

So the property is,

> The sum of digits in the binary equivalents is two

Or

> The binary equivalents of all these have two `1`s and six `0`s.
>  Looking at the binary equivalents of the alphabets, one can see that no other alphabets share this property

The title (*Thanks to [@trolley813](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/21511/trolley813)*):

> <strike>Two might refer to the sum of the digits, which is indeed two!</strike>
>  Title might mean that the sum [of digits in] letters is not different from two [but is equal to two]

---

*Old (and wrong) answer*

The property is:

> The index if each alphabet is equal to the sum of indices of the preceding alphabets in the sequence +1.

And,

> There is no other alphabet with the index `1+2+4+8+16+1 = 32`

Comment: You've got it. Binary was what I was looking for but there are some other interesting patterns came out of this puzzle. I have added another hint in case anyone wants to have a go without looking at your answer. For the same reason, I'll wait a couple of hours before I accept it. well done!

Comment: @Eagle Some refinement about the title, it probably should read "sum [of digits in] letters is not different from two [i.e. equals to 2]"

Comment: Thanks a lot @trolley813 ! I've edited it

Comment: @trolley813 - Close but actually more of a play on words. Rot13(Fhz (Fbzr) yrggref ner abg gjb (gbb) qvssrerag) with Rot13(Fhz) and Rot13(gjb) giving clues to what I was looking for  ;-)

Comment: A bit contrived, I know, but left room for a couple of hints.

Answer (score 20):

The property is that

> each of their alphanumeric values (A=1, B=2, C=3...) is a power of 2.

Comment: That wasn't what I was looking for but is indeed true and is possibly a side effect of the answer that I was looking for so +1 but I won't mark it as accepted yet.

Comment: @ElPedro: It is a side effect, but it hinges on rot13(jurer gur nycunorg fgnegf ba gur NFPVV gnoyr. Vtaber gur svefg ovg bs gur NFPVV inyhr (orpnhfr vg vf nyjnlf 1 naq arire punatrf sebz N gb M), ohg QB erzrzore gung vg nyjnlf pbagevohgrf gb bar bs gur gjb 1-ovgf va lbhe vagraqrq nafjre. Vtabevat gur svefg ovg, N rssrpgviryl fgnegf ng ahzrevpny inyhr 1, naq rirel "cbjre bs gjb" yrggre nqqf rknpgyl 1 1-ovg gb gur pbhag, juvpu rkcynvaf jul obgu nafjref ner pbeerpg. Vs N unq fgnegrq ba n qvssrerag NFPVV inyhr, vg znl abg unir orra gur pnfr.)

Comment: @Flater - Thanks for the explanation. It makes complete sense. As I said, some pretty interesting things have come out of what I at first though was a pretty simple puzzle :)

Answer (score 9):

Is it

> All the letters, symbols in this group have ASCII codes of form $2^m + 2^n$ where m and n are integers

Thus we have

> From [ascii code table](https://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap4/subsection2.1.1.1.html),
>  $A = 65 = 64 + 1 = 2^6 + 2^0$
>  $B = 66 = 64 + 2 = 2^6 + 2^1$
>  $D = 68 = 64 + 4 = 2^6 + 2^2$
>  $H = 72 = 64 + 8 = 2^6 + 2^3$
>  $P = 80 = 64 + 16 = 2^6 + 2^4$

Other letters don't share this property because

> 64 + 32 = 96 which does not correspond to any letter. The letter `a` begins at 97

For the newer hints

> $0 = 48 = 32 + 16 = 2^5 + 2^4$
>  $( = 40 = 32 + 8 = 2^5 + 2^3$

Comment: Obviously moving in the right direction with the ASCII table.

Comment: @ElPedro I guess Akari has formalized the informal property of my answer much better in his answer

Comment: Still a good answer though :)

Comment: I like the format of this answer more than the accepted one, simply because that's how I internally rephrased the accepted answer before even reading this one :) +1

Answer (score 7):

I think it's:

> Each letter's alphanumeric value is double its predecessor, which also means, sum two times the alphanumeric value of the previous letter

This means that:

> Starting from A=1 we get the sequence 1,2,4,8,16,... which corresponds to the sequence A,B,D,H,P

Comment: Welcome! Again, a great answer but not exactly what I am looking for. +1 all the same.

Answer (score 6):

> Each time you add the position of the letter (A is 1 and B is 2), the next letter's position is the sum of the previous +1.
> Thus, 1+2 is 3, +4 is 7, +8 is 15, +16 is 31. You can't continue the problem because there are only 26 letters in the alphabet.